# Slurm Error: Error in saveRDS(fit, paste("outputs3/fit_", mod, ".rds", sep = "")) : error writing to connection

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I have a batch script that I am trying to run. I've made some changes to the original script (which ran and saved successfully) so I wanted to rerun the models and save to a different output folder. I now get the following error in SOME models, but not in others. About half of the models save successfully, the others display this error and the model objects are very small in size with little information saved to them.

```
    Error in saveRDS(fit, paste("outputs3/fit_", mod, ".rds", sep = "")) :
      error writing to connection
```

The error doesn't seem to be in the file path itself, since some of the models are successfully saved. It seems too that this error occurs part-way through saving the object, since the objects still show up in the folder but are 0B or very small in size compared to the full model output objects.

Why is this error selectively occurring? Would it be a problem with permissions? Or a problem with storage quotas?

Comment: Are you sure it is a SLURM issue?

Comment: Your title says "Slurm Error" but saveRDS appears to be an R function.  You're suggesting it could be a quota or permissions issue, which it could, but that'd be a filesystem problem, not a slurm problem.  You might get better answers if you provide more details about your R program and your environment

Comment: @frymaster @Poshi apologies, I'm trying to use a cluster run the scripts, but I'm not an expert on the terminology. I get this error when I look at the slurm output using ```nano slurm-jobid.out```

Comment: Looking at it more, it seems like it's only happening to the last 6 or so jobs that are trying to be saved to the folder. saveRDS is the R function that is failing which causes the job to terminate with exit code 1. I am trying to determine why saveRDS is working for some of the jobs in the batch but not others.

Comment: Does the folder `outputs3` actually exist in the working directory?

Comment: It was a memory issue; there was not enough available memory for the files to be saved to the file location.